# swarmplot palette in power bi doesn't change the color

Tags: python, powerbi, swarmplot

I am trying to work with power bi and python by creating a single dimension clustering with swarmplot.

Everything is perfect except the color scale that I assign to it. This is my code. X="Centros" (crosses) and hue="Equipos" (teams).

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fig. ax = plt.subplots()

sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="muted")
sns.swarmplot(x="Centros", hue="Equipos", palette=["red","coral","linegreen","forestgreen"],s=13, data=dataset,hue_order=['00-20','20-40','40-60','60-80','80-100'] )

plt.show()```

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnAqH.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a dictionary into palette argument with the hue's categories... such as:
`sns.swarmplot(x='centros', hue='equipos', data=dataset, palette={'real':'yellow', 'barca': 'red', 'atletico': 'blue'})`.

It worked for me.